# The flow to pack php/js/css and deploy to web server

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm developing an website now. 
I found there are lots steps to do before deploying the code to web server.

e.g. 
1. compact JS/CSS/HTML 
2. Run unit test if any
3. Test code locally 
4. Upload code to web server

Not sure if anyone could share your experiences on this process? Or how does facebook/google/yahoo ... do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment strategy entirely depends on your project. None of those steps (except uploading code to web-server of course) is mandatory for running PHP web-site. Those steps appears when you are trying to:

1. Utilize build system (for configs generation, JS and CSS minification, etc);
2. Write unit-tests and (probably) run continuos integration;
3. Establish quality assurance by having QA go/no go before deployment of new release.

Needless to mention that to make, for instance, JS/CSS minification or perform unit-tests execution, you need to implement ones first.

That's why I'd not advice you to follow cargo-cult and copy all features of smbd's project (even facebook or google). Instead just follow the project needs and build your own deployment strategy.